# WANt to use table variable in @dtAttendance dt in below mentioned oracle query

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

(how to write below code in oracle)
WANt to use  table variable in @dtAttendance dt in below mentioned oracle query
dont no how to use

```
   PROCEDURE uploadShiftRoaster 
            (
            V_ShiftName varchar2  ,
            V_UpdatedBy Date DEFAULT null  ,
            
            V_TowerPk varchar2
            
           
            )
            as
            begin
                UPDATE A
                    SET A.ShiftName = dt.ShiftName, 
   A.ShiftStartTime=DATEDIFF * INTERVAL '1' dayA. AttendanceDate -'1900-01-01' +
               TO_CHAR(S.ShiftStartTime (8)),
                    A.ShiftEndTime=DATEDIFF * INTERVAL '1' day.AttendanceDate 
                case when dt.ShiftName='NIGHT' then -1 else 0 end +TO_CHAR(S.ShiftEndTime (8)),
                
                    A.ModifiedBy = V_UpdatedBy,
                    A.ModifiedOn = systimestamp
                    from T_ATTENDANCE_ATTENDANCE A join @dtAttendance dt on A.LoginId = dt.LoginID and A.AttendanceDate = dt.AttendanceDate 
                    left join T_ATTENDANCE_SHIFT_MASTER S on S.Shift=dt.ShiftName 
                    where a.AttendanceDate between systimestamp-1 and interval '+30' day + systimestamp
                    and A.LoginId in (Select LoginId from T_ATTENDANCE_USER_ATTENDANCE_TEAM where TowerPk = V_TowerPk and isActive = 'Y')
            end uploadShiftRoaster;
```

Comment: In order to join a table that is unknown at compile time, you need dynamic SQL. Having to do this often indicates an inappropriate data model. There is no `UPDATE ... FROM` in Oracle 11g. Oracle only supports standard SQL update statements, i.e. `UPDATE table SET ... WHERE ...` and `UPDATE (query) SET ... WHERE ...`. For the latter the DBMS must see it guaranteed that the query result only contains one row for each row in the updatable table. Your best bet may be [MERGE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606).

Comment: can we create table variable in oracle as we create in  sql

Comment: No. There is no variable table in Oracle statements. You must build the SQL string inserting the table name. This is called dynamic SQL.

Comment: DateAdd(Day,DateDiff(Day,0,AttendanceDate),Cast(S.ShiftStartTime as varchar(8))),                           can you help me above code to convert from sql to oracle

Comment: It seems you are coming from SQL Server. Their date functions/operators are horrible. I don't know what the code is supposed to do. You should know, though. And once you know, you can look up date and time functions in Oracle. Be aware though, that Oracle neither has a time nor a date data type. They have `DATE` which is a misnomed datetime. A date is considered the datetime at midnight. If you dn't find anything helpful, then make this a separate request. Tell us what the code is doing in SQL Server and how to do the same in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a collection:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE exampleProcedure (
  v_dates SYS.ODCIDATELIST
)
AS
BEGIN
  UPDATE table_name
  SET    updated = 1
  WHERE  date_column IN (SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE(v_dates));
END exampleProcedure;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (date_column, updated) AS
SELECT DATE '1970-01-01' + LEVEL - 1, 0 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Then if you call the procedure:

```sql
BEGIN
  exampleProcedure(
    SYS.ODCIDATELIST(DATE '1970-01-01', DATE '1970-01-04', DATE '1970-01-05')
  );
END;
/
```

Then the table will be updated to:

| DATE_COLUMN | UPDATED |
| --- | --- |
| 1970-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 1970-01-02 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 1970-01-03 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 1970-01-04 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 1970-01-05 00:00:00 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/oL_dpL9t)